# How to extract a substring from a list of strings in a nonconstant context using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a txt file formatted in this way: (`<s>=space character, <t>=tab character, <n>=end line`)

```
1<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<s><t>some comment<n>
2<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<n>
3<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<s><t>some comment<s><t>another comment<n>
4<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<s><t>some comment<n>
5<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<n>
6<s><t>some text<s><t>translated text<n>
.
.
```

As you can see, there are comments in some lines and in others not. I would need to group the line number and also the only text translated using perl regex. I'm having trouble ignoring the rest of the line after "translated text".
I tried two versions:

`/^(\d+)\s+(?:[^\t]+)\t(.+)(\t|$)/gm`

- this regex works if there are no comments but it does not divide the translation from the comments in the other lines.

`/^(\d+)\s+(?:[^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)/gm`

- this regex works with the lines that have comments but not for the others as it stops at the first tab of the next line

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Please don't add useful information like this in a comment. Instead, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58911154/edit) and add it there.

Comment: PS: I am trying these regexes using an online regex tester.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the third tab and everything that follows:

```
 $line =~ s/^(?:[^\t]*\t){2}[^\t]*\K\t[^\n]*//;
```

Comment: If there is no comment there is not even the third tab :(

Comment: Your example searches 2 times for 0 or more non 'tab' characters and a 'tab' (in my example text: "line number" + "some text"), then searches again for 0 or more non 'tab' ("translated text") and reset (\K). Now continue searching for a 'tab' (third 'tab') but if the string is finished ("some comment" is omitted) there is no 'tab' and your example, in this case, does not work. I would like it to work both when there is "some comment" and when there is not.

Comment: It doesn't match when they're is no third tab, but that's fine because there is nothing to delete of there is no third tab. So it *does* work

Answer (score 0):

This regex does the job I expect:

```
/^((?>\d+))(?:(?>\s+))(?>[^\t]+)\t((?>[^\t\n]+))/gm
```